# Stress energy tensor for a spherically symmetric mass

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Stress energy tensor contains information about the source of curvature in general relativity.

If we want to write the stress-energy tensor for a spherically symmetric mass with constant density, what would it look like? How will the tensor change when the mass is rotating slowly? How does one go about writing the components of the tensor for such a case? Also, what should be the choice of coordinates?

I am not talking about Schwarzschild. It was the case for a vacuum.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric answers at least some of this.

Comment: You are right. That is the vacuum solution. Then see chapter 10 of A first course in general relativity by Schutz. Sorry that is not an online answer.